# Javascript interaction with React interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a help page with the questions in a collapsible format where the user will only see questions on the page. When they click the question they would like, the answer appears as an expandable/collapsible item.

I have the html written and the css. Everything works correctly in a developer instance (through w3 schools) but in my web environment, which uses React, I'm having problems.

Here is what I came up with for the Javascript but I don't think I'm writing the React functions correctly and the Javascript does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// help page collapsible interface
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }

// provide collapsible interface on help page ready event
document.addEventListener('cdm-custom-page:ready', function(){
});

// and provide collapsible interface on help page update event
document.addEventListener('cdm-custom-page:update', function(){
});

// and cleanup javascript on help page leave event
document.addEventListener('cdm-custom-page:leave', function(){
});

}
```

Comment: Where is React here? Looks like vanilla JS

Answer (score 0):

This is the plain html, css and javascript method. React does not work in that way. Firstly you need to learn some of the important rules in react, like never modify the dom elements directly.
Means you shouldn't use this code.

```
document.addEventListener('cdm-custom-page:ready', function(){ });

document.addEventListener('cdm-custom-page:update', function(){
});

document.addEventListener('cdm-custom-page:leave', function(){
});
```

If you want to use the collapsible in react then I would suggest you to use some of the good UI libraries, Like Ant Design, Material UI or React Bootstrap.

You can check out the AntDesign Collapse [here](https://ant.design/components/collapse/) 
For the Material UI check the collapse [here](https://material-ui.com/api/collapse/) 
For React bootstrap checkout [this one](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/) 
and If you want to build the custom one. You can consider [this one](https://codepen.io/Sinanski/pen/rzLRdE) also.

Comment: Thanks so much for the resources!